# SCSS: concat files but not compile

Tags: webpack, sass, gulp, node-sass, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm looking for easy way to **concat** **scss** files(that contain imports) into single **scss** file,

not **compile** but **concat**.

More details:
Our SCSS is compiled on-fly based on variables from database, so it it's not possible to compile it before deployment. But I still would like to do some optimizations to help server-side compiler - to concat many files into single one.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `grunt-contrib-concat` to only **concat** as you mentioned:

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            'sass/*.scss',
        ],
        dest: 'sass/build.scss',
    }
}
```

ref: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#concat-task

Comment: thank you for you answer. My issues is with dependancies: scss file has imports inside.